# How to integrate basic packages into Android Source

Tags: linux, sudo, raspberry-pi3, android-7.0-nougat

I am using Android 7. I compiled the source for Raspberry PI platform.
I don't have the necessary packages in my user-space. Packages like,
sudo 
apt-get
apk 
vi and etc.,

How to get those packages as a default.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but if you're running Android on your Pi, rather than a traditional Linux distribution, I wouldn't expect console tools like apt-get and vim to be available. I don't really understand why you would install Android if you wanted to use these kinds of tools, when they come as part of the standard kit with Raspian, etc. What is your objective here?

Comment: I need to test the blue-tooth module profiles in the RPI-3. We were planned to use the raspberry pi with android for our project. So, I cannot proceed with the linux. I want to add necessary packages into my BSP.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's no concept of a "package" in Android, apart from the APK package. So you're in a difficult position from the very start. If you want to install development tools like vim on Android, and use them with a terminal emulator, that's certainly possible. However, you'll have to build them from source to suit your particular environment. You might find compiled binaries lurking about, and some of them might even work. But Android isn't designed to be used the way you are using it, so you'll have to expect a certain amount of head-beating.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion  @Kevin Boone